# FQL query to stream still returning unreliable results?

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-fql

I am trying to use FQL to query the stream table and retrieve news feed items. Like this:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message, created_time 
FROM stream 
WHERE filter_key in 
    (SELECT filter_key 
     FROM stream_filter 
     WHERE uid=me() 
     AND type='newsfeed'
     ) 
AND is_hidden = 0
```

Following the suggestion [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/), I've been trying to use epoch timestamps (created_time) to limit the number of items returned and paginate everything (seems like a kludge, but OK, if that's the best we can do). However, any time I specify the cutoff as earlier than a day or so (haven't nailed down the exact pattern yet), it returns null. No error message... just "data": [].

I know there have been a lot of issues with paginating the stream table in the past, but this seems like an old bug (if it's still a bug and not my oversight). Has anyone figured out how to deal with this? I can get better results if I leave any reference to filter_key out of the query, but I need to use it, so that's not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and I fixed it by removing the

filter_key in 
    (SELECT filter_key 
     FROM stream_filter 
     WHERE uid=me() 
     AND type='newsfeed'
     )

from my query. What I did was initially did a query to get the filter key, and saved the filter_key string to then use in all my subsequent queries. This worked for me